# Processing vector to raster faster with R

Tags: raster, r, rasterization, rgdal, parallel

I am converting vector to raster in R. However the process was too long. Is there possibility to put the script into multithread or GPU processing in order to do it more faster?

My script to rasterized vector.

```
r.raster = raster()
extent(r.raster) = extent(setor) #definindo o extent do raster
res(r.raster) = 10 #definindo o tamanho do pixel
setor.r = rasterize(setor, r.raster, 'dens_imov')
```

r.raster

class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 9636, 11476, 110582736  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent      : 505755, 620515, 8555432, 8651792  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0

setor

class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 5419 
extent      : 505755, 620515.4, 8555429, 8651792  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=24 +south +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
variables   : 6
names       :    ID,CD_GEOCODI,   TIPO,  dens_imov,area_m,domicilios1 
min values  : 35464, 290110605000001,  RURAL, 0.00000003,100004,1.0000 
max values  : 58468, 293320820000042, URBANO, 0.54581673,99996, 99.0000

Print of setor
[image]

Comment: Can you post summaries of setor and r.raster? I'd like to have some idea of the number of objects in setor and the dimensions of r.raster. just print them is fine

Comment: I put summary in body of question.

Comment: Not summary, just print - the info I asked for us not tgere

Comment: Sorry, I put the print.

Comment: Ah, disappointed I didn't think of this until I saw the print-out - make sure the raster's projection matches the polygons, it doesn't at the moment - try r <- raster(setor); res(r) <- 10; setor.r = rasterize(setor, r, 'dens_imov') - but also try, setting res(r) <- 250 first so you get an idea of how long the high-res version will take

Comment: There is some nice work in the fasterize package that provides an alternative to the raster packages rasterize function. For going the other way, raster to polygon, there is the spex package. Both of these packages are available on CRAN with GitHub development sites as well.

Comment: Use fasterize package.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I tried to **"parallelize"** the function `rasterize` using the `R` package `parallel` in this way:

1. split the *SpatialPolygonsDataFrame* object in `n` parts
2. `rasterize` every part separately
3. merge all the parts into one raster

In my computer, the parallelized `rasterize` function took **2.75** times less than the no-parallelized `rasterize` function.

**Note:** the code below download a polygon shapefile (~26.2 MB) from the web. You can use any SpatialPolygonDataFrame object. This is only an example.

#### Load libraries and example data:

```
# Load libraries
library('raster')
library('rgdal')

# Load a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame example
# Load Brazil administrative level 2 shapefile
BRA_adm2 <- raster::getData(country = "BRA", level = 2)

# Convert NAMES level 2 to factor 
BRA_adm2$NAME_2 <- as.factor(BRA_adm2$NAME_2)

# Plot BRA_adm2
plot(BRA_adm2)
box()

# Define RasterLayer object
r.raster <- raster()

# Define raster extent
extent(r.raster) <- extent(BRA_adm2)

# Define pixel size
res(r.raster) <- 0.1
```

[image: BrazilSPDF]

**Figure 1:** Brazil SpatialPolygonsDataFrame plot

#### Simple thread example

```
# Simple thread -----------------------------------------------------------

# Rasterize
system.time(BRA_adm2.r <- rasterize(BRA_adm2, r.raster, 'NAME_2'))
```

**Time in my laptop:**

```
# Output:
# user  system elapsed 
# 23.883    0.010   23.891
```

#### Multithread thread example

```
# Multithread -------------------------------------------------------------

# Load 'parallel' package for support Parallel computation in R
library('parallel')

# Calculate the number of cores
no_cores <- detectCores() - 1

# Number of polygons features in SPDF
features <- 1:nrow(BRA_adm2[,])

# Split features in n parts
n <- 50
parts <- split(features, cut(features, n))

# Initiate cluster (after loading all the necessary object to R environment: BRA_adm2, parts, r.raster, n)
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores, type = "FORK")
print(cl)

# Parallelize rasterize function
system.time(rParts <- parLapply(cl = cl, X = 1:n, fun = function(x) rasterize(BRA_adm2[parts[[x]],], r.raster, 'NAME_2')))

# Finish
stopCluster(cl)

# Merge all raster parts
rMerge <- do.call(merge, rParts)

# Plot raster
plot(rMerge)
```

[image: BrazilRaster]

**Figure 2:** Brazil Raster plot

**Time in my laptop:**

```
# Output:
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.203   0.033   8.688
```

**More info about parallelization in R**:

- [how-to-go-parallel-in-r-basics-tips](http://gforge.se/2015/02/how-to-go-parallel-in-r-basics-tips/)
- [parallel-computing-in-r](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2016/01/parallel-computing-in-r/)
- [running-r-jobs-quickly-on-many-machines](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2016/01/running-r-jobs-quickly-on-many-machines/)
- [Parallelizing and Clustering example in R](https://github.com/guzmanlopez/parallelizingAndClusteringInR)

Comment: Very good answer!

Comment: Do you not just set n as the number of cores on the machine?

Comment: @Sam I think it should work without problem but I don't know if it's better or not! I assumed that if I splitted the **features** in **n** parts equal to the **number of cores** maybe one of this parts could be easier to process and the core that processed it would be without use! However, if you have more parts than cores when one core finish processing one part it would take other part. But certainly, I'm not sure! Any help on this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: i'm going to run some tests tonight. On a small shapefile (roughly 25km by 25km), rasterized to 50m, there is a tiny improvement in using n = 2,4 or 8 against n = 20, 30 or up to 50. I'll sub in a very large shapefile tonight and rasterize to 25m. Single core processing is 10hrs so we will see what different values of n do!! (n=50 is just under 1 hr)

Comment: @Guzmán I am runnig the code again. However, it returened some error and a don't know why. Can you help me?
 Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  7 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'BRA_adm2' not found

Comment: @DiogoCaribé I have updated the answer: please check the modifications in `getData` function from the `raster` package and convert to factor the names of the level 2 administrative boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

try `fasterize`, no more need to parallelize

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fasterize/vignettes/using-fasterize.html

Comment: I should note that I am getting very reasonable speeds with rasterizing vector data using the terra package. I have not benchmarked it but, the performance seems fairly comparable to fasterize, to the point that I needed to operationalize a rasterization process, for creating sample grids and masks, in a large scale analysis and just ended up using terra, after comparing with fasterize. There may be a measurable difference when rasterizing a large number of features and would be interesting to test.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of Jeffery Evans comment on the `fasterize()` answer.

The `rasterize()` function within the `terra` package works very well out of the box.

I recently converted the [WPDA](https://www.protectedplanet.net/en) features (1.9GB vector, 90k records) to 2.5 arc min grid in about 2 minute per layer. That is perfectly fast for me.