# Add county attribute to gSSURGO soils raster

Tags: raster, r, attribute-table, rasterization

I have a high-resolution (10m cell size) raster of soils data for a US state. Pixel values are the map unit key (mukey) from gSSURGO. Every soil type has a unique mukey, but a given mukey can occur in one or more counties within a state.

I am trying to merge data into this raster attribute table, but the data I'm trying to merge has unique values for each mukey *in each county that mukey occurs in*. Consequently, I cannot make the merge until I first add a county field into the raster attribute table.

My current approach to doing this is to `raster::rasterize` a polygon .shp file of the state's counties to the same resolution as the gSSURGO data. Since the cell sizes are SO small, however, this is taking in incredible amount of time. Even with 8 cores on a fast machine...

Is there another good way to do this?!

I prefer to do this with R, but can use ArcMap instead if that can do it more quickly.

Here is the R code I am using for the `raster::rasterize` approach in parallel. I found this approach [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213225/processing-vector-to-raster-faster-with-r). With this approach I was able to process one county on each of my 8 cores in 1.5 hours. And I've got a whole country to do!

```
IL_soils_raster <- raster("MapunitRaster_IL_10m.tif")
us_county_polygons <- readOGR("cb_2016_us_county_500k/cb_2016_us_county_500k.shp")

IL_county_polygons <- us_county_polygons[us_county_polygons$STATEFP == 17,]
IL_county_polygons  <- spTransform(IL_county_polygons, CRS = crs(state_soils_raster))

cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
clusterEvalQ(cl, {library(raster)})
clusterExport(cl, list("ST_counties", "st_soils"))
rParts <- parLapply(cl = cl, 
                    X = 1:nrow(IL_county_polygons[,]), 
                    fun = function(x) rasterize(IL_county_polygons[parts[[x]],], IL_soils_raster, 'COUNTYFP'))
stopCluster(cl)
ST_counties_raster <- do.call(merge, rParts)
```

Comment: can you post the code you're using please? This sounds like a familiar problem...

Comment: original post updated with code above.

Comment: Hmm ok. So after rasterising, what's your end goal? Soil attribute rasters mapped out by each soil type? Soil attributes for each soil type that vary by county?