# Parallel rasterizing with GetCover option?

Tags: raster, r, rasterization, rgdal

I'm trying to rasterize a shapefile in parallel using the solution from this post: [Processing vector to raster faster with R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213225/processing-vector-to-raster-faster-with-r)

However, this fails to give the correct answer when the `GetCover = T` in the rasterize`function.

Has anyone successfully rasterized in parallel with the GetCover option enabled?

Comment: How is the answer not correct when you use `getCover=T`? Is the raster nonsense? Wrong in places? Upside down? Please provide a full reproducible example, even if its mostly a copy of the one in the linked Q - that would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what is not working, but this works for me:

```
library(raster)
p1 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-140,55), c(-10, 0), c(-140,-60), c(-180,-20))
p2 <- rbind(c(0,0), c(140,60), c(160,0), c(140,-55), c(0,0))
pols <- spPolygons(p1, p2)
r <- raster(ncol=90, nrow=45)

library('parallel')
cl <- makeCluster(2)
z <- clusterEvalQ(cl, library("raster"))
clusterExport(cl, c("r", "pols"))
clusterExport(cl, "r")
p <- parLapply(cl = cl, X = 1:length(pols), fun = function(i) rasterize(pols[i, ], r, getCover=TRUE))

x <- sum(stack(p))
x <- reclassify(x, cbind(1,Inf,1))
plot(x)
```

I would just do

```
y <- rasterize(pols, r, getCover=TRUE)
```

In the current version of `raster` that is pretty fast. And it also works if you have overlapping polygons, while the parallelized version would be close but not exactely the same.

Comment: thank you @RobertHijmams. You are correct. The problem was not the rasterize part but the combination of tiles afterward. I was erroneously doing `do.call(merge, p)` which takes only the first value when rasters overlap. Thanks again for your help.