# R: rasterize SpatialPolygonsDataFrame and keep factor field

Tags: raster, r, rasterization

I want to rasterize a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame and keep the values of a factor column.

Consider the following code (from [Processing vector to raster faster with R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213225/processing-vector-to-raster-faster-with-r)):

```
library('raster')
library('rgdal')
# Load a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame example (Brazil administrative level 2) shapefile
dat <- raster::getData(country = "BRA", level = 2)

# Convert NAMES to factor 
dat$NAME_1 <- as.factor(dat$NAME_1)

# Define RasterLayer object
r.raster <- raster()

# Define raster extent
extent(r.raster) <- extent(dat)

# Define pixel size
res(r.raster) <- 0.1

# rasterize
ras <- rasterize(x = dat, y = r.raster, field = "NAME_1")
```

To access the values from column `NAME_1` I tried:

```
ras_factor <- ratify(ras)
levels(ras_factor)
```

There are no factor values.

Where do I find the original values from column `NAME_1`?
How can I rasterize a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame and transfer the factor values to the resulting `ras` object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ratify` is the right option, but you should do an extra step. You need to create a dictionary to store desired values and create a numeric column to be used in `rasterize` process:

```r
library('raster')
library('rgdal')
# Load a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame example (Brazil administrative level 2) shapefile
dat <- raster::getData(country = "BRA", level = 2)

# get names
nam <- unique(dat$NAME_1)

# create a data.frame
nam_df <- data.frame(ID = 1:length(nam), nam = nam)

# Place IDs
dat$ID <- nam_df$ID[match(dat$NAME_1,nam_df$nam)]

# Define RasterLayer object
r.raster <- raster()

# Define raster extent
extent(r.raster) <- extent(dat)

# Define pixel size
res(r.raster) <- 0.1

# rasterize
ras <- rasterize(x = dat, y = r.raster, field = "ID")

# ratify raster
r <- ratify(ras)

# Create levels
rat <- levels(r)[[1]]
rat$names <- nam_df$nam
rat$IDs <- nam_df$ID
levels(r) <- rat

rasterVis::levelplot(r)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this procedure may give an error if you use the `"ID"` field. I have an `"ID"` field in my attribute table. This field contains a different value than `"FID"` that ArcMap displays in its attribute table. It seems that using the argument: `field = "ID"` causes confusion. I solved this problem by creating a new `"codigo"` field which contains the same values as my `"ID"` field.

```
catastro_ras <- rasterize(catastro, raster, field= "codigo")
```